# Save as a matrix instead of an structure

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have several `.txt` subjects and I want to turn them into `.mat` files and then save them. My problem is that since my data is massive (100 matrices that each one is at least 200 Mb) I have to use a for loop, and in each iteration load the `.txt` file into a variable like A, then save it. for each iteration I do something like this:

```
s = fileName(i);
A = load (s); % A is a matrix
save (s, 'A');
```

The problem is that when the third line executes, it saves a structure. And then I have to load this data again and use `struct2array(...)` to convert it into a matrix. I used save '(s, 'A', '-mat')' but I failed again.

Is there any way to save my data as a `.mat` file with the name that I want?

Comment: If you are saving an array, the array will be in the `*.mat` file (you can confirm this with `whos -file filename`). By specifying an output to `load` the data will always be *loaded* into a structure.

Comment: @excaza Not when you're loading `.txt` files.

Comment: @dasdingonesin that's why I said `*.mat` file...

Comment: @excaza He's `load`ing the data from `.txt` files, right? When you use `load` for ASCII files, you obviously have to specify an output variable, which is going to be a double array. [see doc](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html)

Comment: @dasdingonesin I'm well aware of what `load` does with ASCII files vs MAT files. That's not where the issue is, please *read* the question.

Comment: @dasdingonesin I'm glad you were able to understand the question by whatever means necessary.

Comment: @excaza When I load the data into A, and then use Whos A, I get a 196000*130 double. This is a matix, Am I right? And when I save it and then again load it into an other variable like E, Whos E gives me a 1*1 size, and When I use struct2array, I get my desired matrix form.

Comment: The trick is after saving it, when you load it again, to use `load(s)` instead of `E = load(s);` This will load `A` as a matrix.

Comment: @A.bolbol Yes, this is the expected, documented behavior. If you specify an input to `load` when loading a `*.mat` file, the variables are loaded into a structure. This is a *good* thing, because omitting the explicit output variable arbitrarily adds variables to the workspace.